# Python Error: name 'admin' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-urls

I am creating a Python application in Django for the first time. I know that I must uncomment the admin tools in the urls.py, I have done that. I have also added `autodiscover`. Everytime I try to add a new feature to the administration panel, I get this error:

"NameError: name 'admin' is not defined"

Here is the code I am using in my model to add to the admin panel:

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3

    class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['question']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]
```

here is the code in the python terminal I am using

```
admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

and here is the code from my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'iFriends.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^iFriends/', include('iFriends.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

Anyone have any idea why it cannot find the admin name?

**EDIT**

Here is my entire model file:

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text


#COMMENTED OUT UNTIL I FIX THE ADMIN NAME
from django.config import admin

class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3

    class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['question']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]

#ADD THIS TO THE MAIN PYTHON FUNCTION
admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

Comment: is 'django.contrib.admin' in your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: yes, it is. I have already added a "Polls" section to the admin panel using this same method. Now it's not working

Answer (score 11):

`from django.config import admin` should be `from django.contrib import admin`

Answer (score 6):

at the top of your `**url.py**` file, add the following code

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```

So it that particular block should look something like the following

---

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
**from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()**

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'examplesite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^examplesite/', include('examplesite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    #url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
**url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),**

)
```

Answer (score 2):

i change my urls.py like this... this should be the basic format

```
from django.conf.urls import  include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well after an long, agonizing quest to fix this stupid problem, I FINALLY came across the answer! Another Django programmer ran into the same problem and found this:

IN THE PARENT OF ChoiceInLine (which you'll see as 'admin.StackedInline' in the tutorial), THE L IN StackedInline SHOULD NOT BE CAPITALIZED ... It's as simple as that ... thankyou SO much Karen Tracey ...

http://grokbase.com/p/gg/django-users/133v4wx0sx/django-1-5-tutorial-error-module-has-no-attribute-stackedinline

Comment: Does this answer the question?  `StackedInline` seems to be capitalized correctly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you don't have `from django.contrib import admin` in your model file where you defined `ModelAdmin` classes, `class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):`.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the admin code (everything after #COMMENTED OUT UNTIL I FIX THE ADMIN NAME) to admin.py

Answer (score 0):

A way to fix this for me was to add this in the beginning of `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
```